# .htaccess RewriteRule to change some php pages inside a specific directory

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change some .php files located in www.mywebsite.com/en/.
For example:

```
iscrizione.php --Rewrite to--> subscription.php
programma.php --Rewrite to--> program.php
```

How can I do that with some `RewriteRule(s)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /iscrizione.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/en/subscription.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /programma.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/en/program.php[R=301,L]
```

Or

```
Redirect 301 /en/iscrizione.php https://www.mywebsite.com/en/subscription.php
Redirect 301 /en/programma.php https://www.mywebsite.com/en/program.php
```